# Custom UIView class allways crash when initialized

Tags: swift, uiview, swift2

I've created a simple custom UIView class.

```
    import Foundation
import UIKit

class customShop : UIView{

    var bannerViewHight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var bannerViewTop: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var bannerViewLeft: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var bannerViewRight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var banerDiscount: UIImageView!
    var bannerImageShop : UIImageView!
    var bannerTitle : UILabel!
    var bannerDescription: UILabel!
    var bannerButton: UIButton!


    override init (frame : CGRect) {
        super.init(frame : frame)
        self.bannerTitle.text = ""

    }

    convenience init () {
        self.init(frame:CGRect.zero)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("This class does not support NSCoding")
    }
}
```

I'm instantiating this way:

```
var mainView : customShop = customShop()
mainView.bannerTitle.text = "hola"
let desc = super.getLanguageFromDict(self.areaDetailValues.texts_description)
```

As you can see in the image, it crashes always when I try to set any value. How this can be?

[image]

Comment: bannerTitle doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, these are not outlets, and I don't see any initialisation code. What you should do is actually create that label via:

```
self.bannerTitle = UILabel()
```

or with frame so you are sure that you can see that label:

```
self.bannerTitle = UILabel(frame: frame)
```

second one will create the view with the size of the view.

I would suggest you to create xib file and connect outlets - it will be easier for you to maintain the view and see changes on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

`bannerTitle` is not initialized when you try to update its text. Change:

```
var bannerTitle: UILabel!
```

to:

```
var bannerTitle: UILabel! = UILabel()
```

or, more concisely,

```
var bannerTitle = UILabel()
```

What you're doing with your variables (the `: UILabel` part) just specifies what type the objects are; it doesn't initialize them.